# Finding the invariant lines of a vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

How do I find the invariant lines of the following system:

$x' = x(1-x+y)$

$y' = y(1-3x-y)$

The fixed points of the system are $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0.5,-0.5)\}$

I know there are 4 lines. The invariant lines $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ are trivial.

How do I find the remaining 2?

Comment: $\frac {y'}{x'} = \frac{y}{x} \implies \frac {1-x+y}{1-3x-y} = 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the invariant lines are 4. The other 2 except the trivial $x=0$ and $y=0$ are 
$$x+y=0$$
and $$x+y-1=0$$
This can be seen directly from
$$\frac{d}{dt}(x+y)=-(x+y-1)(x+y)$$
and similarly
$$\frac{d}{dt}(x+y-1)=-(x+y)(x+y-1)$$
If one starts with the parameterization $$ax+by=c\qquad\qquad (1)$$ then for invariance we must have
$$\frac{d}{dt}(ax+by-c)=0$$
or equivalently
$$ax(1-x+y)+by(1-3x-y)=0\qquad\qquad (2)$$
For $b\neq 0$ solving (1) wrt $y$ and replacing it in (2) we obtain
$$\frac{c}{b}(b-c)+\frac{3c}{b}(a-b)x+\frac{2a}{b}(b-a)x^2=0$$
which holds for every $x$ if

a) $a=0$ and $c=0$ (trivial solution $y=0$)

b) $a=b$ and $c=0$ (case $x+y=0$)

c) $a=b$ and $c=b$ (case $x+y-1=0$)

Finally for $b=0$ we obtain the other trivial solution $x=0$.